# Python For loop variable syntax

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, count

I'm trying to make a for loop count up and print values from defined variables

```
Value1 = "X"
Value2 = "Y"
for x in range (1, 2):
  print Valuex
```

So I want this print value1 then value2

What is the syntax for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use an array (also don't start variable names with capital letters):

```
value = [ "X", "Y" ]
for x in range (0, 2):
  print value[x]
```

Also you probably wanted two elements in your range.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach can be to put all values in list and then loop. e.g

```
values = ["X", "Y"]
for x in values:
   print x
```

This will automatically avoid accessing invalid index. while using range you have to be careful to avoid exceptions.